# Pulling data with sysdate using for loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, for-loop, sysdate

I am pulling data and need to get a running iterative count of people that fall within the effective and expire date columns.  For example I need to get a count of members that fall within a month:

```
    m.memid   m.effective_dt   m.expiration_dt
    00010       3/1/14           7/31/15
    00011       1/1/12           1/31/14
    00012       10/1/13          1/31/15


    select  mar2015.nummem032015
           , apr2015.nummem042015

    from (
          select count(distinct m.member) as nummem032015
          from m
          where to_date('31-mar-2015') between trunc(m.EFFECTIVE_DT) and      
          trunc(m.EXPIRATION_DT
          ) mar2015

         , (
            select count(distinct m.member) as nummem042015
            from m
            where to_date('30-apr-2015') between trunc(m.EFFECTIVE_DT) and      
            trunc(m.EXPIRATION_DT
          ) apr2015
```

I am looking for a way to not have to do this for each month.

Output to look something like this:

```
    month     count
    mar2015   1000
    apr2015   2010
    may2015   1900
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where do the three months come from?  Is that a parameter?  Or do you always want, say, the last 3 months prior to the current date?  Or something else?

Comment: I am needing it to go back for the past 3 years.

Comment: The query you've posted appears to produce one row of data with many columns, one per month.  The sample output you posted has multiple rows of data with one row per month.  Which of the two do you want.  Is the logic just to take midnight on the last day of the month and look to see if that is between the `effective_dt` and the `expiration_dt`?  Rather than the first day of the month.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your dedication.  I added an example of what the table looks like that I am pulling from.  I am not too concerned what the output looks like, two columns versus 40 columns.  I am arbitrarily using a date to get a count of members.  I am doing some monthly analysis so I picked the end of the month to count all members that had an active span during that month.